# How to make background color of div change according to what image is generated?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a random image generator, and I have it put inside of a div. Is there a way to change the background color of the div according to which image in generated? (Keep in mind when answering that I'm very new to JavaScript)

I've tried adding in div tags around the images in the JS for the generator, but HTML doesn't work inside the script tag (which I figured it wouldn't, but you never know).

I've also tried using

> document.body.style.backgroundColor = "*insert color here*";

but it changes the *entire* background of the page, and I only want the background of the div to change.

The colors in the images are not what I want to change the background color to. I want to set the background color to a color that is most likely completely different. The only thing I want to know is *if it's possible* and *how* to do it.

Ex: The webpage loads x image, so I want the background color of the div to change to purple. When it loads y image, I want the bg color to change to blue, and so on.

This probably seems like a noob question, but if it *is* possible, how do I do it? Would I need to use CSS or HTML, and if so, what would I use?

Comment: Can I see your whole code?

Comment: What value are you trying to get from the image in order to change the background color?

Comment: @moon [link](https://jsbin.com/meceyehusa/edit?html,output)

Comment: I don't think I'm trying to get a value from the image - I just want to change the bg color of the div itself, according to the image that was generated. For example, if x image is generated, then the bg color turns to purple. @CarlEdwards

Comment: Are you saying the colours of the image itself are irrelevant? Rather, you have a list that image x should have purple background, y should have blue, etc.? Please [edit] your question to show the relevant existing image selection code directly in the question body rather than relying on a link to an external site in a comment.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with Color Thief, it identifies the dominant color in an image.

http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/color-thief/

https://github.com/lokesh/color-thief

It's pretty simple to set up, download/clone the source files and make sure to include the color thief script in your HTML

```
<script src="js/color-thief.min.js"></script>
```

Then in your script:

```
var colorThief = new ColorThief();
colorThief.getColor(sourceImage);
```

You can then use this value to set your background color dynamically

```
document.querySelector('boxx').style.backgroundColor = colorThief.getColor(sourceImage)
```